ERROR TThreadPoolServer: Thrift error occurred during processing of message . Error while using Tableau Spark SQL connector
My hive and my spark is inside the main node of my hadoop cluster. I am facing a problem while connecting my hive table to tableau using the spark sql connector with the help of spark thrift server. I am able to connect to my hive tables using beeline, but when i try to connect it using my tableau, i am getting an error in the log saying

When i try to not put any credentials in my tableau, I get this error.

When i try to put my username to login, I do not get any anything as mentioned below and this is where I get the error in the spark error logs

I do not have solution here, hence I came to this platform to get your support
